# React Chartjs not showing with dynamic values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am using chartjs library to show charts in my application. I am using chart in a separate component. The component is showing the chart when the values are hard coded. I want to pass the values from other components and use the same chart in different other components. The chart is not showing with dynamic values.

passing values:

```
<DoughnutChart wrong={wrong.length} right={right.length}/>


const DoughnutChart = (props) => {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);

  const [wrong] = useState(props.wrong);
  const [right] = useState(props.right);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Result',
        data: [wrong,right],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
          'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
        ],
      }]
    };

    // Options for the chart
    const options = {
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Exam Result'
        }
      }
    };

    // Create the chart instance
    const myChart = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: data,
      options: options
    });

    // Clean up function to destroy the chart when component unmounts
    return () => myChart.destroy();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{width:300}}>
      <canvas ref={chartRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DoughnutChart;
```

Comment: Hello:)
This can occur because you have set up the parameters incorrectly or didn't pass them

Comment: Can you show the code about how did you pass these two props?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be related to how you are handling updates to the component when the values change.
You might want to update the chart whenever the wrong and right values change. You can achieve this by updating the useEffect dependency array.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';

const DoughnutChart = (props) => {
  const chartRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Result',
        data: [props.wrong, props.right],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
          'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
        ],
      }]
    };

    const options = {
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Exam Result'
        }
      }
    };

    // Check if chartRef is available before creating the chart
    if (chartRef.current) {
      const myChart = new Chart(chartRef.current, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: data,
        options: options
      });

      // Clean up function to destroy the chart when component unmounts or values change
      return () => myChart.destroy();
    }
  }, [props.wrong, props.right]);

  return (
    <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
      <canvas ref={chartRef}></canvas>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DoughnutChart;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that the chart component is a child component and is redering many times from parent component and it is taking the initial values of zero and zero and renders no chart. I have changed the initial values to one and one and it is rendering but it is not taking the values from props and keep on redering with the initial values. I hope it makes sense.